# Product images lost when editing a product

Tags: product, ce-1.9.1.0, product-images, edit

I have a client with a Magento 1.9.1.0 store. This has been upgraded from version 1.7.x.

This problem has affected the store since the 1.7.x series and we have been unable to fix it with any of the fixes that we have found online.

It appears the problem occurs when an admin goes to edit a product. Once selecting the edit option, some times but not always, the product image will disappear. The admin does not have to save the product, and by the time the cache re-generates the image is missing.

To detail at least some of the fixes we've tried:

- Folder/file permissions
- Re-indexing
- Clearing cache
- Disabling various caches
- New server
- Checking PHP error log

Does anybody have any ideas about this one? Come across it before? Found a fix? Even just how we could begin to gather more information on the problem?

Comment: Try to change the browser that using sometime it is browser issue

Comment: Thanks for your response Bhupendra. Unfortunately this is confirmed on multiple browsers, multiple internet connections and both admins and normal site visitors find the same problem.

Comment: I have the same problem on new installed magento 1.9. This problem appears when subfolders, which contain pictures, have the name in letters or symbols. When subfolders names is in numbers - it is ok. I hope this bug will be repaired.

Comment: I know this is three years later, but I seem to be having the same issue. Has anyone come up with a solution? Thanks!